# Load Optimaizaion Testing For Website

Tags: load-testing

Whats is load testing ? Give me the techniques or process for load testing ? Why my website is very slow ?

Answer (score 0):

> Whats is load testing ?

Load testing a website is the process of subjecting the site to multiple simultaneous users (usually simulated via a testing tool) and measuring the performance.

> Give me the techniques or process for load testing ?

There is no short answer to that. There are many processes, techniques and tools involved in website load testing.

> Why my website is very slow ?

Bandwidth limitations, CPU overload, poor code design, database locking, memory contention...could be any of those and a zillion other possibilities.  You'll need to do some testing to narrow it down.

Judging by your questions, you've never done any performance testing before, so you might want to engage some help.  My company as well as many others offer load testing services that can get answers for you quickly.

Comment: ya, i want some help for performance testing give me the process of it or some guidance and which automated tools are used for performance  testing and load testing plz give it me?  Thanks....In Advance...!!